# preg_match remove whitespaces accepts line break

Tags: php, regex

Is there a possible to write regexp, which removes all whitespaces but accepts line breaks?
Maybe it is possible to write it in other way?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to match just a space and a tab using regex. Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
\h+
```

ie horizontal whitespace or `[ ]+` is what you are looking for.

`\h matches any horizontal whitespace character (equal to [[:blank:]])`